# Ionic 3 error 404 apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, http-status-code-404

I am not getting access to an API after building the application `ionic cordova build android --release --prod` and to run ionic `cordova run android`. It returns Error 404 in a get method.

Testing locally works (`ionic service`).
I already researched here in the stack but as solutions available does not solve my problem. Researching in other locations is also not finding an effective solution.